# How to force azure eventhub checkpointstoreblob to terminate after xx seconds

Tags: azure-functions, python-3.6, azure-iot-hub

Hi I have an Azure function (http trigger) that read data from an IoT hub, based code from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio_1.1.2/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob). What I am trying to do is terminate the azure function after 58 seconds, I tried the classic way is to store the current time when I started the azure function and in the `on_event()` function, test if time elapsed exceeded 58 seconds, but it's doesn't work and it's not pythonic ! how can I achieve it as I looked in the doc if there is a parameter to pass when calling `on_event()` function to terminate the process and couldn't find any.

Here is what I did:

- In my `__init__.py` file :

```py
from . import eventHubHelper

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        # start consumer
        logging.info('************* Starting consumer ***********')
        # store current time
        os.environ["TIME"] = str(time.time()) 
        eventHubHelper.consumer()
```

- and in the `eventHubHelper.py` file I have the base code which reads events from IoT hub:

```py
def on_event(partition_context, event):
    # get the time
    start = float(os.environ["TIME"]) 
    print("################## current exec time: "+ str(time.time() - start) + " seconds")
    if time.time() - start > 58:
        start = 0
        print("#################### execution time " + str(time.time() - start ))
        # return http response but doesn't work
        return func.HttpResponse("############ execution time: "+ str(time.time() - start) + " seconds")
    print("Received event from partition: {}.".format(partition_context.partition_id))
    print("Telemetry received: ", event.body_as_str())
    print("Properties (set by device): ", event.properties)
    print("System properties (set by IoT Hub): ", event.system_properties)
    # store events in table storage
    store_to_ts(partition_context.partition_id, event.body_as_str(), event.properties)
    partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)

def on_error(partition_context, error):
    # Put your code here. partition_context can be None in the on_error callback.
    if partition_context:
        print("An exception: {} occurred during receiving from Partition: {}.".format(
            partition_context.partition_id,
            error
        ))
    else:
        print("An exception: {} occurred during the load balance process.".format(error))

def consumer():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(
        STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, 
        BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME
        )
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$default",
        eventhub_name=EVENTHUB_NAME,
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store
        
    )
    try:
        with client:
            client.receive(
                on_event=on_event,
                on_error=on_error
            )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Receiving has stopped.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think AF has write access to ENV variables  os.environ["TIME"] = str(time.time()).

Store the start time in redis cache(any external cache) on the first call of event and comapre against that cached value. Don't forget to clear cached value.

Or take a look at durable function to manage state(start time in your case). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode

Comment: Thank you for your comment, actually I did what you said I store the start time in a variable and each time I compare with the actual time, and to close the connection is to do `client.close()` with the code mentioned from above, for people reading this in futur there is a code for this purpose: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/recv_for_period.py

Comment: ok, the 3d way is use timer and go asleep. Actually there is a   difference in handling messages in AzureFunction or EventHubConsumerClient, because the latter can have state